# Does $V/(\ker f \cap \ker g) \cong \text{im} f +\text{im} g$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank, exact-sequence

Let $k$ be a field and $V$ be a finite dimensional $k$-vector space. Let $f$ and $g$ be two $k$-linear endomorphisms of $V$ such that $f\circ g=g\circ f$.

Do we have an isomorphism of $k$-vector spaces $V/(\ker f \cap \ker g) \cong \text{im} f +\text{im} g$ ?

Many thanks!

Comment: Should even be $\oplus.$

Comment: @Chickenmancer,  not if $f=g$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A counter-example seems to be 
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$
B=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Comment: AB=BA=0, and if (e_1,e_2,e_3) is the canonical basis, imA=k*e_1, imB=k*e_1, kerA=k*e_1+k*e_3 and kerB=k*e_1+k*e_2. It is a counterexample, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** In my answer I did not consider the assumption $f\circ g=g\circ f$.

The claim is **wrong**. Consider the maps
$$f:=\left[\matrix{0&0&0\cr0&0&0\cr 1&1&0\cr}\right],\qquad 
g:=\left[\matrix{0&0&0\cr0&0&0\cr 1&0&1\cr}\right]\ .$$
Then $${\rm ker}(f)={\rm span}\bigl((1,-1,0),(0,0,1)\bigr),\quad
{\rm ker}(g)={\rm span}\bigl((1,0,-1),(0,1,0)\bigr)\ .$$
Therefore ${\rm ker}(f)\cap{\rm ker}(g)={\rm span}\bigl((1,-1,-1)\bigr)$ has dimension $1$, hence $V/\bigl({\rm ker}(f)\cap{\rm ker}(g)\bigr)$ has dimension $2$. On the other hand $${\rm im}(f)={\rm im}(g)={\rm im}(f)+{\rm im}(g)={\rm span}\bigl((0,0,1)\bigr)$$ has dimension $1$.

Comment: Do we have $fg=gf$ here?

Comment: @PeterFranek: You are right. I did not consider this assumption.